# Android jellybean usb computer connection not allowed

Tags: android

I have just bought a new lenovo A3500 (A7-50) tablet with 4.2.2 jellybean system .my computer is running on widows 8.
when i connect my tablet via usb cable the compuetr don't sense the device and i can't find it on the device manager even as (other devices). I tried allowing usb debugging in (developer options) but nothing changed.So i tried to change the way the tablet connects to the computer by going to Settings > Storgae >(menu)> USB computer connection  but i found it not allowed as in the following image.
http://mousomashakel.webuda.com/a3500usb.jpg

Answer (score 1):

I have Windows 8 and a Lenovo A3500-FL (A7-40) where I can reproduce your screenshot by unplugging the USB cable. Are you sure your USB cable is working? I have a few cables that only work sporadically after a year of usage.

Comment: Had the same problem, tried another cable, and it worked. (Win 7)